# High Scores! From ACM 2017

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    testcases = int(input())
for i in range(testcases):
    n = int(input())
    names = []
    for a in range(n):
        names.append(input())
    prefix = ''
    for b in range(len(names[0])):
        for c in names:
            if c.startswith(prefix) == True:
                common = True
            else: common = False
        if common == False:
                break
        prefix += names[0][b]
    print(prefix)
```

I am given a list of names and I need to find the common prefix that applies to every name. My program works, but always returns one more letter than is supposed to be there. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If the current prefix matches all the entered names, you add one more character to it.  When it fails to match, you break out of the loop - but the character that caused the failure is still attached to the end of `prefix`.

There are various ways to fix this, but one possibility is to just remove the last character by adding this statement outside the loop:

```
prefix = prefix[:-1]  # python slice notation - remove the last element
```

There are some style issues with your code.  Those would be best addressed on CodeReview rather than Stackoverflow.

I would have done it this way (after replacing your input statements with a hard-coded test case):

```
x = ["Joseph", "Jose", "Josie", "Joselyn"]

n = 0
try:
    while all(a[n] == x[0][n] for a in x[1:]):
        n += 1
except IndexError:
    pass
print(x[0][:n])
```

This script prints "Jos".

Comment: If I break out of the loop, does it still run the code that is underneath the break? Because my prefix += comes AFTER the break, so I would think that it would not run it if it breaks. @paul

Comment: The previous time through the loop you added a character to the end of `prefix`.  You don't break out of the loop until after you tested `prefix` and it FAILED.  So `prefix` at that point already contains a string that fails; the string that succeeded must be shorter by exactly one character.  The break statement just exits the loop so of course the code that follows will execute.

Comment: Hmm. Is there a way to fix this without doing prefix[:-1]? I want to learn how to actually fix this and not just add in a workaround. Thanks @paul

Comment: It's not a workaround but a necessary step in your algorithm.  A better approach, I think, is to test every string character by character, without ever building a test string at all.  I edited my solution to present this approach.